# What is Connector in PowerApps

Tags: connector, powerapps

I am learning PowerApps and while I am surfing on this, I come across Connector and Connections which are main components before proceeding with actions/triggers. So, could you please explain in detailed what is connector and connections on PowerApps?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

A **Connector** is a proxy that sits between PowerApps/Flows and the backend service. This can either simply pass information and requests
along to the backend service or it can change the request going out or the response coming back from the service. 
You can create Connectors for things like OneDrive, Twitter, ShrePoint, Facebook etc. and then use those in your app.

A **Connection** holds all of the configuration information for the user so that you can use a specific Connector. This could be 
authentication information such as username and password, database name, environment, etc. Each time you log in to a connector with different credentials, you are creating a new Connection for the same Connector.

PowerApps **Datasources** can hold additional configuration information 
for the Connection. For example, a datasource can use a SharePoint connection and will provide further information on which Site 
and List specifically it is referencing.